# C# and SQLCE Database Not Updating

Tags: c#, sql, database

Ok, I have been having a problem the last few days with my database not updating.  I can read the data fine and I'm not getting any exceptions either.  I'm trying to update the database then I try to read values again after the update (during same run), and they still hold the original values, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with the database being copied to another folder (I'm using Copy if newer yet neither database is being updated).

Here is the code I'm using.  As you can see I tried a few different approaches, none of which worked yet.

```
public void UpdateDatabaseInStock(string itemName, string tableName)
    {
        DataSet data = new DataSet("Items");
        int val;
        //get the file path to the database as a string
        string dbfile =
            new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName +
            "\\Database\\GameData.sdf";
        //connect to the database
        using (SqlCeConnection cntn = new SqlCeConnection("datasource=" + dbfile))
        {
            //create an adapter to pull all data from the table
            using (SqlCeDataAdapter adpt = new SqlCeDataAdapter
                ("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE Name LIKE '%" + itemName + "%'", cntn))
            {
                //put the data into a DataSet
                adpt.Fill(data);

                cntn.Close();
            }



            //fill the data from the Items table into a DataTable to return.
            DataTable itemTable = data.Tables[0];

            DataRow a = itemTable.Rows[0];

            val = (short)a.ItemArray[3] - 1;

            dbfile = "";
            data.Dispose();
            itemTable.Dispose();


            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cntn;
            cntn.Open();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET [In Stock] = @Value WHERE [Name] = '@ItemName'";
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
            //cmd.Parameters["@Value"].Value = val;
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemName", SqlDbType.NChar, 75);
            //cmd.Parameters["@ItemName"].Value = itemName;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", val);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", itemName);


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       
            //close the conenction
            cntn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas to get it to actually update?

Comment: Have you tried checking in the database if the update proceeded?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be proceeding at all.  Every time I look at the values in the actual database or pull them in with code, they have the same starting values.

Comment: What data type is your Name column and are you passing in an exact `itemName`?  Your where clause differs between your `select` and your `update`, which is not necessarily bad but you may be capturing more rows with `LIKE '%" + itemName + "%'"` than with `[Name] = '@ItemName'`.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the differences, and I do anticipate issues down the road which I'll fix.  I was more concerned about getting it to update first however.  The data type was nchar(75) by the way and it was the issue in the update where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch (can't corroborate this on msdn): could it be that using nchar(75) adds spaces to the parameter, thereby causing the WHERE clause to fail?

Comment: Ok, you may have been onto something.  I don't exactly know if its for the reason you stated, but the where clause was failing.  It didn't seem to know how to handle the string correctly.  So I pulled the ID column (a number) instead and used that in the where clause and it worked perfectly.  So thanks!